# groupingBy List of Object instead of Map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Having below class

```java
class Train {
  String type;
  List<RateInfo> rateInfos;
}
```

want to groupBy type and needs to return as List

rateType will be AC, general, VIP

Here I am grouping by rateType.

```java
Map<String, List<RateInfo>> collect 
    = rateInfos.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RateInfo::getRateType));
```

Instead of collecting as `Map<String, List<RateInfo>>`, I want to collect it as `List<Train>`.

the `List<Train>` will have always 3 elements(based on `rateType`)

```
for example:

[rateType:"AC", roomTypeInfos: [n nmuber of values], rateType:"general", roomTypeInfos: [n nmuber of values], rateType:"economy", roomTypeInfos: [n nmuber of values]]
```

how to transform it?

Comment: Is the input `List<RateInfo>` and the output `List<List<RoomTypeInfo>>`?

Comment: input is List<RateInfo> and output is List<Train>. which has type and List<RateInfo>

Comment: @Remo is `rateType` same as the `type` defined in `Train`?

Answer (score 1):

I think each grouping is to be mapped into a `Train` object.
Create a constructor for the `Train` class with `type` and the list passed as arguments. Then update your current code as:

```java
// This generates a List<Train>
rateInfos.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RateInfo::getRateType))
          .entrySet()
          .map(entry -> new Train(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `Train` may be updated with a constructor accepting a `RateInfo` parameter. and a merge function needs to be implemented.

Also, `merge` function needs to be implemented to add appropriate `RateInfo` to the list in the current instance of `Train`.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Train {
    String type;
    List<RateInfo> rateInfos;

    public Train(RateInfo rate) {
        this(rate.rateType, new ArrayList<>());
        this.rateInfos.add(rate);
    }

    public Train merge(Train that) {
        this.rateInfos.addAll(that.rateInfos);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then it could be convenient to use `Collectors::collectingAndThen` along with `Collectors::toMap` to build a map with `rateType` key, and convert to the `List<Train>`:

```java
List<RateInfo> rateInfos = Arrays.asList(
        new RateInfo("AC", 200),
        new RateInfo("AC", 300),
        new RateInfo("General", 400),
        new RateInfo("General", 500),
        new RateInfo("General", 750),
        new RateInfo("VIP", 800),
        new RateInfo("VIP", 1000)
);

List<Train> merged = rateInfos.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toMap(RateInfo::getRateType, Train::new, Train::merge, LinkedHashMap::new), // Map<String, Train> created here
                map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()) // from Collection<Train>
        ));

merged.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Train(type=AC, rateInfos=[RateInfo(rateType=AC, rate=200), RateInfo(rateType=AC, rate=300)])
Train(type=General, rateInfos=[RateInfo(rateType=General, rate=400), RateInfo(rateType=General, rate=500), RateInfo(rateType=General, rate=750)])
Train(type=VIP, rateInfos=[RateInfo(rateType=VIP, rate=800), RateInfo(rateType=VIP, rate=1000)])
```